# Compress and Encrypt a Byte Array in C

Tags: c, encryption, binary, embedded, compression

I have a program which generates byte arrays `unsigned * char` and sends that data out over a wireless stream using fwrite.

I would like to compress and encrypt that byte array into another byte array, but since I am running the code on an embedded system, I'd rather not load new libraries; I would rather write out the compression and encryption functions on my own.

So, in other words my program is as follows:

```
void send(STREAM* s, unsigned* char byteArr) {
  fwrite(s, byteArr);
}
```

Instead, I would like to create a function:

```
void send(STREAM* s, unsigned* char byteArr) {
    unsgiend* char compressedArr = compressCharArr(byteArr);
    unsigned* char encryptedArr = encryptCharArr(compressedArr)
    fwrite(s, encryptedArr);
}

unsigned* char encryptedArr(unsigned* char byteArr) {
  // make the encrypted byte array (?)
}

unsigned* char compressedArr (unsigned* char byteArr) {
  // make the compressed byte array (?)
}
```

My question is: what simple algorithms could I write out on my own that will accomplish this in C? I would prefer to us something that only involves standard C code, no libraries, just math, for-loops, etc.

As for encryption, I understand encryption requires keys/passwords on both ends of the communication. That is fine, lets assume that the keys are shared and we are using symmetric encryption.

I don't mind using the same algorithm as zip, 7zip, gzip -- I know those compression systems also include encryption/password protection. I'm just not sure how to implement it simply without inserting libraries, DLL's etc onto the embedded system.

PS - My syntax may be off with fwrite() since I am not near my code now. I hope my coding example shows my intention clearly.

ADD:
I'd to mention, the C code is running on a chip called "Atmega168" ... so if using libraries is the only solid way to go, can anyone recommend libraries that are optimized for this type of chip? http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega168.aspx

Comment: you are caring about too much things for a single question, your question is also unclear, for example _encryption_ it's not necessarely about user input or passwords, you are also introducing new problems that are typical of the networking solutions such as data corruption and reliability of the network/communication ( just to name 2 ), and you are assuming that compressed data it's always best for some reasons. In my limited experience I think that you need a layer that can let's you abstract some more and it will take care about protocols when you will put in your files as you wish,try 0mq.

Comment: here it is a link http://www.zeromq.org/

Comment: The wireless protocol is BlueTooth so I feel the data should be sent reliably. I could be wrong though... So far in testing, the data has come through fully, though I was using the Java DataInputStream readfully method to get the data

Comment: I know about 0MQ, but from the perspective of a queuing and task delivery system across many different systems. This is just 1 embedded chip to another.

Comment: If you encrypt before you compress you won't get any compression.

Answer (score 4):

It is **not** a good idea to write your own encryption algorithm. Not even, if you copy it. There are many sidechannel and other unexpected attacks to that it is really discouraged.

Instead, I recommend that you use a well-known secure algorithm like [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) (since you are on software) or [3DES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triple_DES) (should you ever want a hardware approach). If you are really *that* resource constrained that you need a faster algorithm, there are also extremely fast symmetric ciphers called "Leightweight Symmetric Ciphers" but this is a new field and it is probably beyond your application's scope.

My recommendation is to use a library that has these algorithms and is optimized for the device you are using (they are often designed with some assembly part that is very fast). If you can compile against them statically you should not have any more overhead than by coding yourself. But their code is most likely faster and more secure.

Regarding compression: Just keep in mind to compress before you encrypt, there are various reasons like speed, size & entropy to do it this way. I have heard of some attacks on compressed data that was encrypted afterwards, but I cannot find them right now. I would not regard this a problem unless you are doing something extra-critical (think: impact like SSL/TLS on general internet communication).

Comment: The wireless stream I am writing to is BlueTooth, but I'd rather opt for encrypting the data myself that using a lot of BT overhead with pairing codes, etc. If I recall in my security seminars, wireless uses RC4, which is a symmetric encryption. -- So I suppose I should look into an RC4 library optimized for my chip?

Comment: `RC4` is a stream cipher while `AES` and `DES` are block ciphers. A stream cipher is generally fast but also less studied and not as well understood. As a base rule you should say: If you can use block ciphers, use them. If it is really infeasible, use a fast but secure stream cipher. But finding one is hard: RC4 is not really secure any more. You may want to look at [eSTREAM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ESTREAM) but as you can see: Good Stream Ciphers are currently hard to find.

Comment: Yeah, come to think of it, we are not using streams, but blocks. I added some information to my question, namely the type of chip we are running the C code on: http://www.atmel.com/devices/atmega168.aspx

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason for you to write your own compression or encryption code since it's already been done for you with massively tested free code, doing so would be a waste of time, and rolling your own would be incredibly prone to errors and security vulnerabilities.

You can use existing code in embedded systems.  [zlib](http://zlib.net/), for example, can be compiled to use no other libraries at all.  You don't need to "load" a library.  You can simply link in the compression routines as if you had written them yourself.

The same is true for AES, with [many](http://www.literatecode.com/aes256). [implementations](http://www.aescrypt.com/). [out](http://www.openssl.org/). [there](http://www.gnutls.org/).